# i3: Open window in whatever workspace command was run from

Tags: user-interface, customization, window-managers, i3

I have the problem that some apps are slow to start up, so I want to be able to run a command and continue to work in another workspace while I wait for the application to start.  I want the application to start in the workspace it was run in.

How can I configure i3 to do this?

There must be some technique either using [placeholder windows](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html) that swallow up the windows you want or by tagging the window to be opened with a workspace number and configuring i3 to recognize those tags and place the window on the appropriate workspace.

I'm surprised there is not a simple solution built in.